# angular ng-repeat with value defined or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, angularjs-ng-repeat, undefined

controller part:

```
$scope.values = [{name:'sasasa',address:'bnbnnb',phoneNumber:''},{},{},,continues];
```

Html part:

```
    <span ng-repeat='value in values'>
    name:{{value.name}}
    phone number:{{value.phoneNumber}}</span>
```

my intentions are like if `phoneNumber` is not present it should print in `DOM` like `NA` how can I achieve this should I use `angular.isDefined` in `HTML` part. I'm new to angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the binding are JavaScript-like code snippets. As such we can use vanilla JS to set the default value if the value of phoneNumber is empty. 
The following code checks if the value of Phone number is a truthy value using the || operator.
If value is truthy(resolves to true), it sets the value of the phone number to the value passed by the object. 
If the value is falsy, the expression evaluates to the String you provided i.e. 'NA'.

```
<span ng-repeat='value in values'>
   name:{{value.name}}
   phone number:{{value.phoneNumber||'NA'}}
</span>
```

For the details on falsy and truthy values:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

For the documentation on Angular expressions check out https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 0):

```
phone number:{{value.phoneNumber || 'NA'}}
```